# Loading local html file in webview while loading pages

Tags: android, webview

Is it possible to load an existing local file to play a loading gif, while waiting for pages to load on the webview ?

I couldn't find any subclasses in the WebView class to override in order to achieve this, please help.

Comment: I know how to load a local file, I just need to do it while waiting for pages to load in the webview, please read the questions properly before writing comments.

Comment: `for pages to load on the webview` ? A multiple? Only one i would say.

Comment: `to play a loading gif,` ? To play a gif you mean?

Comment: The gif you want to play is inside app resources (resources folder) or user phone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That will not do. Just take two WebViews. Display the one with the gif while the other is loading. On page loaded switch visibilities. (View.GONE and View.VISIBLE).